# How can I specify a specific URL in an API controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Right now, my API controller has 2 methods: one to get ALL events, and one to get ONE event.

```
namespace HobbsEventsMobile.Controllers
{
    public class EventController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/event
        [HttpGet]
        public List<HobbsEventsMobile.Models.Event> Get()
        {
            return HobbsEventsMobile.Models.Event.GetEventSummary();
        }

        // GET api/event/5
        [HttpGet]
        public HobbsEventsMobile.Models.Event Get(int id)
        {
            return HobbsEventsMobile.Models.Event.GetEventDetails(id);
        }
    }
}
```

Newly requested functionality requires me to add a way to call events for the current week. I have a stored proc and a method to call this, but I am not sure how to specify the URL. I would like to add this:

```
[HttpGet]
public List<HobbsEventsMobile.Models.Event> Get()
{
    return HobbsEventsMobile.Models.Event.GetThisWeeksEvents();
}
```

but make it accessible at `m.mydomain.com/api/event/thisweek` (or something). **How do I do that?**

Comment: Have you tried [attribute routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)?

Comment: @jasonp I'm not sure what that is. So.... Probably not? Can you elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two different options depending on what version of ASP.NET Web API you're running.  If you're on version one you can simply follow the convention based routing and use:

```
public class EventController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public List<HobbsEventsMobile.Models.Event> ThisWeek()
    {
        return HobbsEventsMobile.Models.Event.GetThisWeeksEvents();
    }
}
```

You will also need to modify your route definitions to support an action name (by default the framework picks the method based upon the HTTP verb):

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "DefaultApiWithId",
    "api/{controller}/{id}",
    new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }, new { id = @"\d+" }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "DefaultApiWithAction",
    "api/{controller}/{action}"
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    "DefaultApiGet",
    "api/{controller}",
    new { action = "Get" },
    new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("GET") }
);
```

If you're using version two, you can still use the convention based routing, but you also have the ability to use attribute routing:

```
public class EventController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("event/thisweek")]
    public List<HobbsEventsMobile.Models.Event> ICanNameThisWhateverIWant()
    {
        return HobbsEventsMobile.Models.Event.GetThisWeeksEvents();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using version one, and implemented this as reflected in your first example. However, now I get an error when making an api call to /event:  `Multiple actions were found that match the request: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[HobbsEventsMobile.Models.Event] Get() on type HobbsEventsMobile.Controllers.EventController` `System.Collections.Generic.List`1[HobbsEventsMobile.Models.Event] ThisWeek() on type HobbsEventsMobile.Controllers.EventController` any ideas?

Comment: @anwyatt I updated my answer with the correct routing modification.  I was thinking MVC style when the routes for Web API are a bit different.